# Problem with [fn]+[F4] and [fn]+[F5] on a Fujitsu Lifebook A 544

Tags: 14.04, fujitsu-siemens

I have a Fujitsu Lifebook A 544 .

It has the following two <kbd>fn</kbd> keys (among others) :

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> : enable/disable the trackpad
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> : enable/disable wireless connections (wifi + bluetooth)

I had a running 12.04 Ubuntu, and the two shortcuts worked as desired.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, the two schortcuts do not work anymore.

My first problem is : I don't know where to start looking for signs of the problems.
These two shortcuts do not trigger any reaction when running `showkey`.
On a Lifebook A 530 running 14.04, these shortcuts work fine.

Can anybody point me in some direction ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for you, but I found a link with a tutorial (in italian, but there are translation services) in order to make Fn keys work on your Fujitsu notebook. 
Here is the link: 
[Tutorial](http://www.webcentrical.net/2014/06/abilitazione-tasti-funzione-in-ubuntu-su-fujitsu-lifebook-ah544/)

Hope it will solve your issue. 
Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, translate it in english, and provide the link for reference.